# Is there a way to prevent a descendant thread from getting into cgroup of its ancestor thread automatically?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, cgroups

I write some threads of my app to a Linux `cpu` cgroup, created by me, explicitly (let us talk e.g. about v1 for now, but if you know a way for v2, that would be also great).

However, I see that descendant threads (created with `pthread_create()` called by their parent thread, which is written to the cgroup explicitly or again after its parent thread) also appear in the cgroup without me writing them directly.

This affects the app not in a good way. Some threads get to the cgroup unexpectedly. You need be always aware of this caveat and be careful e.g. with thread pools etc.

Could you, please, tell if there is a way to solve this problem? E.g., maybe is there a way to forbid descendant threads from getting into their parent's cgroup automatically? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you, please, tell if there is a way to solve this problem? E.g., maybe is there a way to forbid descendant threads from getting into their parent's cgroup automatically?

Although I don't find it documented specifically, that new threads should inherit the cgroup of the thread that created them is exactly what I would expect.  If it weren't so, then it would be unclear what cgroup they should initially have.  Note well that there is no thread hierarchy in pthreads -- all threads of the same process are peers -- so if a new thread did not inherit from the one that created it, then from what thread *would* it inherit?
And, no, I do not know of and did not find any mechanism for establishing different behavior.

Thus, if you want a new thread to go into a different cgroup than the one it inherits at its creation then it needs to be moved there after it is created.  Just like (I presume) you did to assign the creator thread to its cgroup.  If you want to avoid new threads appearing even briefly in a given cgroup, then threads in that cgroup must avoid creating new threads.